# How to access current card id in Trello API

Tags: trello, trello-powerup

How can I programmatically get the currently displayed card id?

Looking through the [Trello API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/power-ups/client-library/accessing-trello-data/) and in particular at the [t.card()](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/power-ups/client-library/accessing-trello-data/#t-card--) call, I'm left wondering if there is further documentation somewhere better describing the allowed fields. According to the snippet the link provides, the first parameter should be `id`, yet in the example it calls a string `'all'`. Is `'all'` some kind of keyword that represents all cards in a board? Is there a keyword for `'thiscard'` or something similar?

All the other calls seems to [require a card ID already](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-id-get), so I seem to be in a catch 22.

I'd eventually like to use this ID to [create a checklist](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-checklists/#api-checklists-post) but this also requires a card ID.

Comment: Think I may have stumbled upon it. Would the correct way be to access it via `t.getContext()`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code snippet to get the card id.

```
/* global TrelloPowerUp */

var t = TrelloPowerUp.iframe();
t.card('id')
    .then(function (name) {
        console.log(name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While I feel the above answer, gives some context.  I went about a different way to solve it.

```
TrelloPowerUp.initialize({
    'card-buttons': function(t, options) {
    return[{
      icon: BLACK_ROCKET_ICON,
      text: 'Track this',
      callback: function(t){
        return t.card('id').then(card=>alert(card.id))
```

My code works at the initialization of powerup.